# How do I make a column name in a table a Primary Key with Persistent?

Tags: persistent, yesod

Here's my model

```
>Test
   testID Int
   product Text
   firmware Text
   startDate Day
   estimatedFinishDate Day
   status Text
   UniqueStartDate startDate
   UniqueEstimatedFinishDate estimatedFinishDate
   UniqueTestID testID
```

I would like testID to be the primary key. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so, I believe:

```
Test id=testID
  product Text
  etc.
```

with persistent >= 0.6.1. ([commit](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/commit/ad904b4e1ecd79b3a7d673fc267c051bced7476d))

Comment: It appears that my other yesod-related packages depend on 0.5.1.